# Batch Title Rename Help

Tags: url-title, sql, title

All of our records (30-40 k) got uploaded with non descriptive titles in a certain channel and I want to properly rename them in either Sequel Pro or EE. I haven't used SQL in a while so I need help creating the proper code.

I'm hoping to have the title and title_url values regenerated based on values of other fields.

Basically I want to be able to do things like:
If field_id_91 = [43987] [vogue-pattern-company] Vogue Pattern Company then title should be "Vogue field_id_40 (field_id_41)"

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you mean the title should be "Vogue Pattern Company field_id_40 (field_id_41)".  I was with you right up until the end.  Otherwise how will we programmatically know to shorten "Vogue Pattern Company" to "Vogue"?  Or are you providing that as part of the input?

Comment: Yea, you got really confusing towards the end there, if you could include a few more examples, then maybe we could help you out.

Comment: Sorry yes I was planning on providing the shorthand of "Vogue" along with the hoping the values of the other field types. I want those field types to generate the rest of the title.